# How to find symmetrical difference using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, difference, symmetric-difference

I've been working on an algorithm that will find the symmetric difference of two arrays (i.e. only items that are in 1 of the 2 arrays, but not both). I've come up with the following so far:

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  let newArr1 = arr1.slice();
  let newArr2 = arr2.slice();
  if (newArr1.length > newArr2.length) {
    return newArr1.filter((item) => !(item in newArr2));
  } else {
    return newArr2.filter((item) => !(item in newArr1));
  }
};

const result = diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(result);
```

But when testing with `diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` the output is `[4, 5]` instead of just `[4]`. The issue seems to happen with whatever the last value of either array is, but I can't seem to figure out what about my code is causing the issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You might be better off working with `Set`. [Here's a handy page](https://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-set-operations.html) that describes operations that might be useful for this problem.

Comment: In addition to spender's suggestion which is likely most performant, another option is to sort the lists and then walk them looking for elements not in the other.  Assuming both lists are generally the same length, this sorting/walking technique will be O(n log n), as opposed to using `.include` which will be O(n^2).  The `Set` option mentioned by spender will be O(n), assuming of course that the underlying implementation of `Set` is a hashed lookup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` operator checks if the value on the left matches a property **name** on the right.

In you want to check if one of the property **values** is in an array, use the  [`includes` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  let newArr1 = arr1.slice();
  let newArr2 = arr2.slice();
  if (newArr1.length > newArr2.length) {
    return newArr1.filter((item) => !newArr2.includes(item));
  } else {
    return newArr2.filter((item) => !newArr1.includes(item));
  }
};

const result = diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I see what I did now, that works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer for another condition

const result = diffArray([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5]);

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2){
  const diff1 = arr1.filter(item => !arr2.includes(item)); // if item not available, the value will be filtered
  const diff2 = arr2.filter(item => !arr1.includes(item));// if item not available, the value will be filtered
  return diff1.concat(diff2);
}
// const result = diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const result = diffArray([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5]); // This condition will fail on the above code
console.log(result);
```